# Could not bind event to each item in array loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to add an event to every image in the document, this is the code:

```
let images = document.getElementsByTagName("img")
const self = this;
for (var img of images) {
  img.onclick = function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      if (!e.target.src) {
        return;
      }
      self.source = e.target.src;
      self.alt = e.target.alt;
  }
}
```

I log all of the images and find that only the last image has the click event. I had tried converting `images` into an array and used `forEach` methods, which got the same result. What's up?
By the way, I do that in Vue's `mounted` hook method.

Comment: The code is totally fine.

Comment: It seems like all images have click events.

Comment: What is `this` here `const self = this;`?

Answer (score 1):

Best way to attach events to multiple DOM elements is to use `Event Delegation`. You should attach the `event` to the parent element and check if the `target` element is `img or not`. Then you can access the `src` and `alt` attributes of the image.

```js
var images = document.querySelector('.images');
images.onclick = function(e) {
  if(e.target.tagName === 'IMG') {
    console.log(e.target.src +" : " + e.target.alt);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="images">
  <img alt="1" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/83.jpg" />
  <img alt="2" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/men/83.jpg" />
  <img alt="3" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/83.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: This is indeed the best way. I think it's worth noting that for matching _non-empty_ HTML elements one should traverse the anchestor node tree of `e.target` until a match is found.

Comment: Yeah it is. But for my project  using Event delegation here will be a bit sticky.